# iOS universal App release but first release iPad only

Tags: ios, universal

I have seen blogs to say we can release the universal App for iPhone first and then add iPad support. I would imagine it should work fine the other way? i.e releasing it for iPad first and adding iPhone support later? Has anyone done this and will Apple sign off the App? I'm in the final leg of a release and iPhone is not going to be ready in time so want to ship the iPad version ahead.

Comment: release iPad only (not universal) and once iPhone is ready update app with universal binary. What is the problem ?

Comment: I didn't realise it was possible to change the App type (i.e universal ) after the first release with the bundle ids etc ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can make an app universal after releasing it in the App Store as an iPad App. Just update the binary when you're ready to release the universal version.